# how to change color of ellipses in wp8 in xaml.cs

Tags: windows-phone-8, colors

i m trying to create a windows phone 8 app.in this app i have 4 ellipses on a page and i want them to change color depending on a certain integer's value every 15 seconds. i have got the timer part down but i m stuck on how to make them change colors. i would really appreciate some help.

i have googled it alot but could not find a clear solution. i m new at apps so please tell me each and every step
here is where i create them in xaml:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="l1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="42,339,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<Ellipse x:Name="l2" Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="111,339,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
<Ellipse x:Name="l3" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="42,471,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<Ellipse x:Name="l4" Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="111,471,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

try implementing this;

```
yourEllipsesName.Fill = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255(R), 255(G), 255(B)));
```

with this you can pass your color code in RGB format. Hope this helps.

Comment: should i add this in xaml or xaml.cs and if in xaml then what do i write in cs code? like i said i m new at this so be very explicit.thanks for your help

Comment: This code is C# code so it goes in the .cs file. It should be called from your timer.

Comment: Yes @ErtayShashko is correct, this is a c# code and it should be called from your timer.

Comment: (+1) Just a remark - depending on the kind of the OP's timer (if its `DispatcherTimer` (which probably is as OP is starting) or other) then may be a need to run this via `Dispatcher` (if not `DispatcherTimer`).

Answer (score 0):

The [solution @Vyas_27](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842884/2681948) provided is the easiest (+1) and in most cases sufficient.

As you are starting, you may want to learn something about [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx). In this case your code may look like this:

In XAML:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="l1" Fill="{Binding FirstBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="42,339,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
// other similar
```

In code behind xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string propName) { if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }

    private Color firstColor = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xF4, 0xF4, 0xF5);
    public Color FirstColor
    {
        get { return firstColor; }
        set { firstColor = value; RaiseProperty("FirstBrush"); }
    }
    public SolidColorBrush FirstBrush { get { return new SolidColorBrush(firstColor); } }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this; // set the DataContext so binding can work
    }

    // Then you change the color like this, and the color of your ellipse is updated
    FirstColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 120, 120, 0);
}
```

You will surely find many blogs, tutorials and so on, so I won't post everything here. Just couple of remarks - what is imortant to make it work:

- in XAML as you can see, define `Binding` to Property (the name is very important)
- your `Page` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - event, and you should provide method which will fire the event
- set the `DataContext` of your `Page`
- properties to which you bind must be public Properties with suitable getter (for OneWay binding)

One remark to my solution and @Vyas_27 - this will work if your `Timer` runs on UI (then it's probably `DispatcherTimer`). If you have timer running on other Thread, then the Color change you must invoke via `Dispatcher`.